# SELECT statement returns first row instead of record that is looked up

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, phpmyadmin

I am trying to select a record from my database, and I am return instead the first one in the table. No matter what I try, the first one gets returned.

Here's the query:

```
$query_task_owner = "select user_id from users where full_name = '$c_task_owner_name'";
$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query_task_owner);
```

Then I try a test to see the value that is returned as such:

```
echo $response or die(mysql_error());
```

This is where I see the user_id of the first row.

Even if I try to put a specific value in the query, as follow, I am getting the same result:

```
$query_task_owner = "select user_id from users where full_name = 'LeBron James'";
```

I do not understand because when I trying this query directly in PHPMyAdmin, I am getting the right result. So the query itself is correct.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fetch `$response` using [mysqli_fetch_array()](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_fetch_array.asp).

```
<?php
$query_task_owner = "select user_id from users where full_name = '$c_task_owner_name'";
$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query_task_owner);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($response,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
echo $row['user_id'];
?>
```

If, users are more related to that `full name`. Then, use `while loop` to `fetch` all record.

```
<?php
$query_task_owner = "select user_id from users where full_name = '$c_task_owner_name'";
$response = @mysqli_query($dbc, $query_task_owner);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($response,MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
  echo $row['user_id']."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: You Were Doing All Correct. Just Missed To Fetch. *No Problem, It Happens With Every One.* **Enjoy Coding** @Armand

Comment: Yeah 1 simple thing that ruins it all if omitted! Thanks again :-)